# NameError: uninitialized constant DeviseController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-7

I have tried upgrading my Rails app from 6.1 to 7 and after running `bundle app:update` I get the following error:

```
rails aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant DeviseController
/Users/martynas/projects/bend/config/initializers/devise_permitted_parameters.rb:17:in `<main>'
/Users/martynas/projects/bend/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => active_storage:update => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Environment:

- Ruby 2.7.5
- Rails 7.0.2.4
- Devise 4.8.1

Any hints how to solve this would be helpful, thanks :)

**Edit**

`devise_permitted_parameters.rb`:

```
module DevisePermittedParameters
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    before_action :configure_permitted_parameters
  end

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys:[:name])
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:name])
  end

end

DeviseController.send :include, DevisePermittedParameters
```

`environment.rb`

```
# Load the Rails application.
require_relative "application"

# Initialize the Rails application.
Rails.application.initialize!
```

Comment: add source of devise_permitted_parameters.rb and environment.rb and check for rails 7 deprecations in case you're using something unsupported in new version

Comment: Hi @Joe, you mean to require `devise_permitted_parameters.rb` inside `environment.rb`?

Comment: No, i meant share you code to see what's inside

Comment: @Joe, sorry for the delay, I have added the two files you asked ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be an issue with devise & rails 7, anyway in one of my project i used devise this way:

**application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.require(:account).permit(:sign_up, keys: %i[email password])
  end
end
```

and in the same file of
**account.rb**,

```
class Account < ApplicationRecord
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :invitable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :confirmable, :validatable
     ......
end

class Account::ParameterSanitizer < Devise::ParameterSanitizer
  def initialize(*)
    super
    params.require(:user).permit(:account_update, keys: %i[password current_password])
    params.require(:user).permit(:register, keys: %i[password email])
  end
end
```

without the need to create `devise_permitted_parameters.rb`

Comment: Yeah, it seems like you are correct about the `devise_permitted_parameters.rb`. I just set up a new project with Rails 7 and the latest Devise gem and there was no such file anymore, so removed it and it seem to work fine. Thanks ;)